# Layout botão em flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

Estou tentando construir um player de vídeo.
No entanto não estou conseguindo deixar o botão do jeito que eu gostaria.

É como se eu precisasse "estender" a dimensão do botão para que o ponto de interseção do borderRadius atingisse o local desejado.

1º Imagem primeiro quadro é como o botão está ficando usando Radius.elliptical

1º Imagem segundo quadro é como eu gostaria que ele ficasse

2º Imagem é uma ilustração da circunferência total do objeto pro ponto de interseção dentro do aspectRatio

3º Imagem é o que acontece se eu uso apenas um Radius.circular

Abaixo o código:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() => runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: PlayerLayout(),
    )
);

class PlayerLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlayerLayoutState createState() => _PlayerLayoutState();
}

class _PlayerLayoutState extends State<PlayerLayout> {

  BorderRadius borderStyle;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    borderStyle = BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.elliptical(60, 120),
      bottomLeft:  Radius.elliptical(60, 120),
    );

  }

  Widget forwardBackward(angle){

    return Transform.rotate(
      angle: angle,
      child: Container(
        child: Material(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: borderStyle
          ),
          child: new InkWell(
              borderRadius: borderStyle,
              onTap: (){print("tapped");},

              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned.fill(
                    left: -32,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.play_arrow,
                      size: 38,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned.fill(
                    left: 0,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.play_arrow,
                      size: 38,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned.fill(
                    left: 32,
                    child:Icon(
                      Icons.play_arrow,
                      size: 38,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
          ),
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green,
            borderRadius: borderStyle
        ),
        height: double.infinity,
      ),
    );

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        top: true,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 16/9,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: forwardBackward(180 * math.pi / 180),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: forwardBackward(360 * math.pi / 180),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Alguém sabe como consigo deixar igual na segunda imagem?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você parece ser um usuário das antigas já, então faz o favor, edite sua pergunta e informa teu código aqui na sua pergunta para nós! É mais prático para te ajudarmos e segue o padrão do site...

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro fiz como aconselhou e acrescentei mais algumas informações! Espero que tenha ficado mais claro!

Answer (score 0):

Não acredito que esteja muito certo fazer um "círculo" para isso.

Fiz de outra forma (não revisei, então pode ser que tenha como melhorar) e não sei se é o que deseja, pois sua pergunta está meio bagunçada:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          height: 150,
          width: 150,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.pinkAccent,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(90),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(90),
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.fast_forward, size: 70),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          height: 150,
          width: 150,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.pinkAccent,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(90),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(90),
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.fast_rewind, size: 70),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

#### Resultado

[image: img]

PS: testado no [dartpad.dev/flutter](https://dartpad.dev/flutter)